# How can I change the command title when running a server?

Tags: process, tcp, lsof

I'm trying to change the output of `lsof -i4TCP:PORT` to include a custom name. This will help me identify the server process as started by my daemon. Below is a picture with arrow pointing to what I'd like to control.

I've created a custom gem, executed the process there, and it still says Ruby. Rather than go down the 'rabbit hole', wondering if anyone else has had this need. I'd essentially like to do exactly what docker has done, and show the process tagged with my program name.

[image: LSOF output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stéphane for the great answer. But in my case the best solution was to bundle my scripts as a Mac OSX app. You can control your process name in your project's Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the process name. On some systems, assigning a value to `$0` would work, but not on Linux (at least not with my version of `ruby`) where `ruby` only sets the arg list (as seen in `ps -f` or `ps -o args`), but not the process name (as in `lsof` or `ps`/`ps -o comm`) (`perl -e '$0 = "foo"'` would work as `perl` sets both the process name and arg list).

For that, on Linux, you need to do a:

```
prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "newname")
```

system call.

While you could do:

```
$ ruby -e 'syscall(157, 15, "foo"); system("ps")'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
5679 pts/4    00:00:01 zsh
8639 pts/4    00:00:00 foo
8641 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
```

The value of the system call would be architecture dependent (here 157 for amd64).

However grepping for `prctl` in the source code of `ruby` doesn't bring any thing so I suspect there's no out of the box support for it in `ruby`. `Process.setproctitle()` also doesn't set the process name.

[@Jessehz on SO has a solution using `fiddle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523684) to make a call to the `pctrl()` function in the C library (assuming a dynamically linked `ruby` I suppose):

```
$ ruby -e 'require "fiddle"; Fiddle::Function.new(
  Fiddle::Handle["prctl".freeze], [Fiddle::TYPE_INT, Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP],
  Fiddle::TYPE_INT).call(15, "foo"); system("ps")'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5931 pts/5    00:00:02 zsh
 8943 pts/5    00:00:00 foo
 8945 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm completely agnostic to language, but I'm primarily running on OSX, which is where I'll be using this technique first. If you were building an app to distribute amongst your coworkers on OSX, whats the easiest way to accomplish a custom group-name for my processes?

Comment: @iangolden, try assigning to `$0`, it might work on macOS. `ruby -e '$0 = "foo"; system("ps")'`